# How do I make sure I don't damage electrical components (L293D, RaspberryPi, & DC Motors)?

Tags: electrical-engineering, microelectronics

I have a RaspberryPi that will control 4 DC motors. I will be using 2 L293d ICs. The 2 ICs will be powered by a 24v 5A Power Adapter.

**Question:**  What other components do I need?

I imagine I would be needing resistors so the ICs don't burn but I am not sure what power rating. I am also worried that I might damage my RaspberryPi. Also, the motors will be connected through a long wire (about 1.5m long) and I am worrying about too much power being lost due to the long wire.

[image]

Comment: Good question! I suggest you make the Question heading shorter.

Comment: What components do you currently have beside the L293D, RaspberryPi, and DC Motors and power adapter?